# Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined

Tags: cordova, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using [this cordova package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions) to check if the user has microphone permission.

This is my code:

```
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;

permissions.hasPermission(permissions.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT, function( status ){
  if ( status.hasPermission ) {
    console.log("Yes :D ");
  }
  else {
    console.warn("No :( ");
  }
});
```

It is exactly as how they had it in their page.

The error i got is the following:

> I20181105-17:21:10.018(4)? 11-05 17:21:07.717  6035  6035 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(348)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined", source: http://localhost:12808/app/app.js?hash=e0190c6fc2d4d0a644cabcdab4c6bd4550cb7c0b (348)

I am using [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and installed the package as follow:

```
Meteor npm install cordova-plugin-android-permissions
```

What am I doing wrong here? why it cannot recognize `hasPermission` function?

Comment: The error message means that `permissions` is undefined. ie the call to cordova.plugins.permissions is returning null. Your code should check for this condition (to prevent this kind of error), but you also need to work out why this is happening - is the plugin correctly installed?

Comment: @Mikkel I believe it is correctly installed, it runs the following code "`var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;` without errors, and I followed meteor docs when installing the package as they mentioned here: https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html

Comment: But it's returning null - if this is a valid condition, your code should handle it without crashing like it does. I think it means something is wrong with your plugin, causing it to be null